# How can I have two different urls for the same page that load two different templates?

Tags: plugins, themes, templates, mobile

I have the following page:

http://liquidchurch.com/messages/

It appears fine on desktop and mobile web.

I'm working on a mobile app and using a web view to encapsulate the page within the app. Problem is I don't want the header/footer to be part of the page when it is viewed in the mobile app, but I do want them to be visible when using either desktop or a mobile browser outside the app.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished or if I'm going about it all wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a rewrite endpoint and a template filter.

First, register a new rewrite endpoint for the `page` post type:

```
function wpd_app_view_rewrite_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'app-view', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_app_view_rewrite_endpoint' );
```

Don't forget to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after adding this (or just visit the Permalinks > Settings page to do this without code).

Now you will be able to add `app-view/` on the end of any page permalink URL, for example, your page will be `domain.com/messages/app-view/`.

The next step is to detect when `app-view/` is present, and load a different template in that case. For the page post type we use the `page_template` filter:

```
function wpd_app_view_page_template( $template ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['app-view'] )  ) {
        $template = locate_template( array( 'app-view-template.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpd_app_view_page_template' );
```

This checks if `query_vars['app-view']` is set in the global `$wp_query` object, and loads the `app-view-template.php` template in this case. This will only be true when the `app-view` rewrite rule matches the current request.

Comment: Hi Milo! Thanks so much for this answer, it is very helpful!

Comment: Do I need to create separate functions for each type of template? e.g., archive, taxonomy?

Comment: You can hook the same function with multiple filters, or you can use `template_include` hook, which fires for all content types.

Comment: Thanks Milo! I am having an issue when I try to set this up using filters for a custom taxonomy, any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291987/rewrite-point-doesnt-work-on-custom-taxonomy