# How Can I Have A URL Changed Based on the Originating URL?

Tags: filters, templates, url-rewriting, page-template, mobile

This is a followup to my question, "[How can I have two different urls for the same page that load two different templates?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/how-can-i-have-two-different-urls-for-the-same-page-that-load-two-different-temp)"

Assuming I implement Milo's answer (registering a new rewrite endpoint, load a different template if endpoint is present), how can I then have links within the page rewritten on the fly to include the endpoint (e.g. app-view).

The page the initial endpoint would be added to is:
https://liquidchurch.com/messages/

Based on Milo's instructions using the rewrite endpoint and page template filter, the url I'd pass from the mobile app would be:
https://liquidchurch.com/messages/app-view/

Now on this page say I click on one of the series, e.g.:

https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/

Problem is this will load with the regular template, not the template created particularly for the mobile view. So somehow I have to pass on to this page that it should be displayed in app-view. So the actual URL the individual should be redirected to would be:

https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/app-view/

In what way could one accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the suggestion given by Milo work on all your pages for the in-app version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `page_link` filter with the same logic as the `page_template` filter in the other answer. If the endpoint query var is set, then any link to a page gets the `app-view/` appended:

```
function wpd_page_link( $link, $post_id ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['app-view'] ) ){
        return $link . 'app-view/';
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpd_page_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi Milo - This doesn't seem to be working for me. The page_template filter works, but when I click on a link from https://liquidchurch.com/messages/app-view/ it displays the page as:
https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/dream-team/
Not as:
https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/dream-team/app-view/
as I expected?

Comment: `page_link` only works for the `page` post type. Each type of content has its own filter- `post_link`, `post_type_link`, `term_link`.

Comment: So, messages is a page, but then the content on it is primarily from a plugin. Is there a way to have it affect a plugin? And what about custom post types?

Comment: I found the post_type_link filter, and tried this:
    `function wp_messages_link( $link, $post_id ) {
     if ( 'lqd-messages' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
      return add_query_arg( $_GET, $link );
     }
     return $link;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wp_messages_link', 10, 2 );`
But this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?