# How Can I Change a Taxonomy URL Based On The Originating URL?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, url-rewriting, terms

I previously wrote a question about [rewriting a URL based on an originating URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291243/how-can-i-have-a-url-changed-based-on-the-originating-url) and Milo provided me with a working answer for pages/posts. But now I am trying to do a taxonomy rewrite and the same functionality seems to break things.

Here is my code:

```
function lqd_series_link( $term_id, $taxonomy ) {
  if ( $taxonomy == 'gc-sermon-series' && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['app-view'] ) ) {
    return $taxonomy; // I've also tried $link
  }
  return $taxonomy;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'lqd_series_link' );
```

What is strangest is what this results in. So if I do the code as Milo instructed on the question linked above I end up with a URL for pages like:

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/app-view/

But when I use the above code I end up with the same exact thing:

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/app-view/

Thoughts?

Comment: Your examples are the same

Comment: @JacobPeattie - Yes, that is what ends up happening. In both cases it creates the same exact link view...which is what I can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`term_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/term_link) filter has a different signature for its callback function than the `page_link` filter, meaning the arguments in your callback are different. (Also note you'll need to explicitly set the argument number when you call `add_filter` because by default `add_filter` will only setup 1 argument. For example:

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'lqd_series_link', 10, 3 ); // Where 3 is the number of arguments for your callback function
```

Then in your callback:

```
function lqd_series_link( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $taxonomy == 'gc-sermon-series' && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['app-view'] ) ) {
        return $url . 'app-view/';
    }
    return $url;
}
```