# Rewrite Point Doesn't Work on Custom Taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom taxonomy (in a custom plugin) for which I have included the argument 'ep_mask' => 'EP_CATEGORIES' for rewrite (this uses WDS' Taxonomy_Core):

```
'args'   => array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_admin_column' => false,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'sermon-series',
                'with_front' => false,
                'ep_mask' => 'EP_CATEGORIES',
            ),
```

I then have in my theme's functions.php file the following instruction to create a rewrite endpoint:

```
function lqd_app_view_rewrite_endpoint() {
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'app-view', EP_ALL);
}
add_action( 'init', 'lqd_app_view_rewrite_endpoint' );
```

When I view say:

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/app-view/

This works perfectly. However, when I try to use it on a custom taxonomy, I get a page not found error:

https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/app-view/

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you're defining EP_CATEGORIES as a *string*, however it's actually a *constant* (defined in WordPress Core). So for example you should define your `ep_mask` like so (without quotes):

```
'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES,
```

You may need to flush the rewrite rules after making this change.